# “BAD” partition showing up in Partition Manager

Tags: windows-xp, troubleshooting, partitioning

I tried to partition my primary hard disk (NTFS partitions) with qtparted and got stuck in the process.  Consequently I had to kill the process and exit my knoppix live CD boot up.

Even though I was expecting XP to get corrupted, it booted fine and showed up all the drives accessible.
But when I opened this with partition manager 8, it shows up as “BAD”. I ran chkdsk /f without any success.
[image]
My objective with qparted and partition magic was to resize my existing partitions and add some space to c:
How do I fix this problem and resize my partitions?

**Edit:** Here's how my primary drive as per Windows is:

[image]

Comment: Windows chkdsk only fixes files within a valid partition. If you have a partition with boundaries that overlap valid partitions, it is "bad" but as long as you don't try to use it, won't interfere with using the "good" partitions. It is a potential hazard, though, and should be fixed with a good partition manager.

Comment: Your first image is broken. Do you happen to have the original that you could reupload?

Answer (score 1):

So `Disk 1` is your system drive?  I note there aren't any partitions on that disk in the screenshot's list.  I'd check the partition table using Linux's `fdisk` utility:

```
$ sudo fdisk -l /dev/sda
```

If that shows an empty partition table as well, you may be able to recreate it with the same fdisk tool, BUT...

The filesystem and data is fine, obviously (since Windows boots).  But without the partition table we really don't know where that filesystem ends.

How was this drive partitioned prior to your resize attempt?  How many partitions, and how big were they?

**NOTE / WARNING / IMPORTANT:** If Windows doesn't know how big its system partition is supposed to be, you stand a real chance of data corruption on any other partitions on that drive.  Windows is currently seeing that drive as one big partition, and disk writes could go anywhere.  Try not to boot into Windows on that drive if at all possible.

Comment: I have added the an image of the drive(how windows shows it now)

Comment: is it still showing no partitions under "disk 1" (like in the first image)?

Comment: yes. it does....

Answer (score 0):

Try the free [Paragon Rescue Kit 9.0 Professional](http://www.paragon-software.com/business/rk-professional/). It can fix several boot problems.
Your first priority is to recover your first disk.
For that, you can use the function of Undelete Partition:

> When simply deleting a partition
>   (without additional wiping) disk
>   management software only removes
>   references to it in the Partition
>   Table, thus leaving the possibility to
>   recover it later. Undelete Partitions
>   option help you find and recover these
>   partitions. A restored partition will
>   be fully functional, as long as other
>   partitions were not created, moved or
>   exceeded the disk space occupied by
>   that partition. This function is only
>   available for blocks of free space.